# How much argument-parsing logic to test?

Tags: unit-testing, argparse

I have a program which may accept several dozen arguments. I am questioning whether there is value in testing every possible argument.

(In the examples, I don't have the exact syntax for pytest readily in my head. If the imprecise pseudo-Python is causing problems, I can edit to something more correct.)

About half of the possible arguments are simply Boolean flags, and the test would probably look something like this:

```
def test_foo_flag_is_set():
    args = ['foo']
    parsed_args = my_parser.parse(args)
    assert parsed_args.foo

def test_foo_flag_is_not_set_by_default():
    args = []
    parsed_args = my_parser.parse(args)
    assert not parsed_args.foo
```

Does testing this provide any value? As far as I can tell, it's basically just going to find out if I make a typo, which I'd expect to be caught by other tools.

Anything more complicated than that, I would want to test, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost certainly using a standard arg-parsing library to process these options. It makes little sense to test the processing like this, since all you're testing is the library code, which is unlikely to have blatant errors in it (and even if it did, you couldn't do anything about it except wait for a fixed version).

What you *should* do is tests that *your* code, given each of those actions, does, in fact, behave noticeably different. In other words, the trigger should be specifying the option, and the tested behaviour should be something that your program does differently as a result.

Comment: Agreed, it is generally not profitable to specifically test third-party library code (though you should certainly prefer third-party libraries that have their own comprehensive test suites). There are holy wars fought daily over what "should" or "should not" be tested. I try to use a pragmatic rule of thumb, "does testing this provide reasonable value for the effort?" and "is it redundant to other tests?" I should also note that how I answer those questions in specific scenarios tends to evolve over time as I gain greater insight into what tests are or are not profitable.